# How do you create a Subversion tag in Xcode 4?

Tags: cocoa, svn, xcode4, xcode-organizer

I can't figure out how to create a Subversion tag in Xcode 4.  I would think it would be in the Organizer -> Repositories interface, but I can't seem to find a way.  In Xcode 3, you could browse the SVN repository, click the "Copy" button in the window's top bar, and then specify the tags/ SVN directory.  I don't see the same type of option in Xcode 4.  Help?

My workaround for now is the command line:

```
svn copy trunkSourceUrl tagsDestinationUrl -m "My tag message."
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alas, as with the ability to merge branches, it would appear tags can't be managed in XCode 4 yet. This is a bit ridiculous considering that, programmatically, creating a tag is exactly the same operation as creating a branch. Guess we're stuck with terminal commands until Apple finally gets their act together about SVN.

Funny that it *did* work in XCode 3.

Comment: After polling for an answer for several months (and using Xcode with SVN), I have to agree that SVN tags aren't supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the top level for your repository, and select it in the right pain of the Organizer.  You will see where you put your username and password.  Under that you will see fields to specify Trunk, Branches, and Tags.  I just put trunk, branches, and tags (as that is customary for svn layouts).  The jewels beside should change to green, and you will see folders for Trunk, Branches, and Tags popup under the repos on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly stated that it did work in XCode 3, and no longer works in XCode 4.
I guess you more or less answered your own question - you can still use XCode 3 for SVN copying, tagging and such. I just tried this, and it seems to work OK with XCode 4 open at the same time. You don't need to open any file or project in XCode 3 to be able to use the 'SCM' menu. Since you won't need to do this often (I guess), it's not a major issue to use two XCode applications at the same time for a short while; otherwise, this could get confusing.

Answer (score -2):

Select the "Root->Tags" directory, create a new directory with the name of the release you want to tag e.g "MyGreat App 1.1"
Select the new directory and click "Import", then select your source code directory and click the "Import" button.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I don't think that's a true tag since it copies data from the local file system instead of from the SVN repository.  Make sense?  The source files for a tag should come from the SVN repository, not the local file system.  I guess you could checkout a project from source control and then just reimport it as a tag, but that runs the risk of introducing unwanted files, and it's more complicated than an "svn copy."  Also, I don't know if revision information would be tracked appropriately with the import approach.